# removing bold styling from part of a header

Tags: html

Is there a way to remove bold styling from part of a header?

```
<h1>**This text should be bold**, but this text should not</h1>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could wrap the not-bold text into a span and give the span the following properties:

```
.notbold{
    font-weight:normal
}​
```

and

```
<h1>**This text should be bold**, <span class='notbold'>but this text should not</span></h1>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MRcpa/1/

Use `<span>` when you want to change the style of elements without placing them in a new block-level element in the document.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want a separate CSS file, you can use inline CSS:

```
<h1>This text should be bold, <span style="font-weight:normal">but this text should not</span></h1>
```

However, as Madara's comment suggests, you **might** want to consider putting the unbolded part in a different header, depending on the use case involved.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can add text inside `<span>` and override css. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmUKa/1/)

html:

```
<h1>**This text should be bold**, <span>but this text should not</span><h1>
```

css:

```
span{
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<h1 style="font-weight: normal;"></h1>
```

try this?

Answer (score 0):

Better one: Instead of using extra span tags in html and increasing html code, you can do as below:

```
<div id="sc-nav-display">
    <table class="sc-nav-table">
      <tr>
        <th class="nav-invent-head">Inventory</th>
        <th class="nav-orders-head">Orders</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here, you can use CSS as below:

```
#sc-nav-display th{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

You just need to use ID assigned to the respected div tag of table.
I used "#sc-nav-display" with "th" in CSS, so that, every other table headings will remain BOLD until and unless you do the same to all others table head as I said.

Comment: The original question regards header tags, not tables, so why did you post an answer containing tables? If a DOM element completely encloses the text to be formatted, then of course you do not need span tags and can use normal css selectors.

Answer (score -1):

It is super simple, By using "font" inside paragraph. An example is shown below:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p><font size="6"> Heading 1</font></p>
```

**Heading 1**

Heading 1

Answer (score -3):

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>This text will be bold.</strong>This text will NOT be bold.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The question was asking how to remove the bold formatting from a header element. This answer shows using a `strong` element within an unordered list item.